# What icon fits "incomplete" and "overridden"?

Tags: icon

When users create widgets in my system, they can leave the billing info incomplete till later. (They eventually have to fill it in unless the requirement get's overridden by a manager.) I need an icon to show in the list of widgets for the incomplete ones and for the overridden ones. Ideally, it would be general, not just specific to billing, in case we decide to treat other info in a similar way.

I've come up with a circle with a pie piece cut out of it, and one with the piece filled in in green, but looking for other ideas....

[image: incomplete icon]
[image]

(Note: this is a B2B web app that will be primarily used by experienced users. Also, the icon won't be the only indicator.)

Comment: I wouldn't use the pie-with-slice unless you're working on Shel Silverstein poems.

Answer (score 2):

1. If the completed icon is green then you can use red, eg like a traffic light.
2. If the completed icon is in color, a gray or white version of the same icon can work.  Make sure you keep the outline though.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here "overridden" means "approved", so I would go with a green checkmark.

For incomplete, I would go with a small picture of your billing info form  withe the bottom missing (shredded-like) and or a question mark. Or the billing form with the bottom part in green and a percentage, like a thermometer.